# .NET Serial Port DataReceived (On/Off)

Tags: .net, serial-port

I'm using the .NET 4 Serial Port Class and a DataReceived handler.

In the DataReceive handler, I remove the handler from the serial port, process the data, and re-add the handler at the end of the function.

```
try
{
  serial_port.datareceived -= new serialdatareceivedeventhandler(ondatareceived);

  // readline and process data
}
catch (exception ex)
{
}
finally
{
  serial_port.datareceived += new serialdatareceivedeventhandler(ondatareceived);
}
```

What are the ramifications, if any, of this usage?  It appears to work just fine, though I haven't tested it long term.  Should I look into a different methodology?  Please give a simple code sample/outline if possible.  Thank you.

Comment: why are you doing so ? to avoid reentry ? btw: you risk loosing some data this way...

Comment: makes me wonder if reentry is actually possible or prevented by the framework

Comment: @yahia - yes, to avoid reentry while processing the data received.  loss of data is not a problem as the device is manually activated, thus I never lose data.

Comment: @BoxerJoe Removing the listener doesn't prevent reentrancy problems. If reentrancy is possible, the event could fire twice before you get around to removing the handler (or perhaps it could even fire after you remove the handler due to race conditions or inconsistent internal delegate operations).

Answer (score 0):

I personally would not remove the handler on every DataReceived Event, it is unneccessary. If you don't get notification of incoming data there is always the possibility of overrunning the existing buffer and loosing information.

I would use something similar to the [Microsoft Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx):

From above MSDN article:

```
 private static void DataReceivedHandler( object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
 {
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
    Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
    Console.Write(indata);
  }
```

Comment: I am doing a database insert inside the handler and wasn't sure if the event was reentrant, also the device I'm handling is manually activated and hence I never lose data.  I just didn't know if there was a catch to doing it like this.

Comment: You are occuring overhead when you attach and detach the event handler. If you do not want it to be reentrant, I probably would take all of the heavy lifting out of the event handler and place the incoming data in a queue and have your database routine monitor the queue for data.

Comment: That's a good idea.  I do need to give immediate realtime feedback to the user regarding the success of recording the event in the database.  One user can only activate the device once every fifteen seconds, but another user can come along and active the device immediately after the previous user. (BTW, looks like you work on some interesting stuff... are those concrete mixing systems?)

Comment: Yes I do installation of concrete mixing systems, plus write the software that keeps the plants full aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about Reentrancy, use a `lock` or mutex:

```
lock(lockobj)
{
    /*Read data from the port here.*/
}
```

Unsubscribing from the event isn't successful to prevent reentrancy because, due to preemptive scheduling (as opposed to cooperative multi-threading or something similar), your code could be preempted just after entering the method (or even before that) before you get a chance to unsubscribe, and more data arrives, triggering the mechanism again.

**In actuality**, the documentation says explicitly,

> [Only one event handler can execute at a time.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score -3):

Regarding this code:

```
catch (exception ex)
{
}
```

Never, ever, ever, ever, ever, ever, ever, ever, ever, ever write code like that.

It's like removing the smoke detectors in your children's bed rooms.

Comment: That's obviously not the actual code... your answer belongs in a comment (or better kept to yourself as it comes off very rude).

Comment: If it's not the actual code, why was it there?  I believe my post to be very helpful.

Comment: What kind of answer is that?